# adding a where clause to show column data to that id?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to echo out the value of 'read_forum' for each row / each sperate 'id' in the row.

so for example:

```
id  |  read_forum(views)  |  content  |

1          30          hello
2          45          bored
3          34          something
```

so on my page i would have:

```
id 1 content: hello     30 views 
id 2 content: bored     45 views
```

and so on.

so basically my question is how do i put a where clause in my sql statement to say echo out id 1's views with id 1 and echo id 2's views out with id 2 all seperately.

i hope im making myself clear. hope someone can help thanks.

```
function check_new_forum2($forum) {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT read_forum FROM ptb_forum WHERE id=$forum
        ";
            $check_new_forum_set2 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_new_forum_set2);
            return $check_new_forum_set2;       
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If one of these answers is correct, please accept it. Same with your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `read_forum` is. Is it your table name, or a column name? Is `ptb_forum` a table name, or the name of the database?

When you open a connection to MySQL you must specify a database name, and any queries only look in that database.

What I *believe* you are trying to do is select all columns of the table `read_forum` in the database `ptb_forum` where the `id` column is a specific value. In that case your query would be (after connecting to the proper database):

```
SELECT * FROM read_forum WHERE id=$forum
```

I will warn you that this query is vulnerable to SQL injection. I encourage you to, at the very least, parse the value to an integer before adding it to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$query = "SELECT read_forum FROM ptb_forum WHERE id=$forum";
```

You should use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ptb_forum WHERE id=".$forum ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a display line, you can concatenate the columns into a human readable string as follows

```
$query =  "SELECT 'id ' || `id` || ' content: ' || `content` 
         || '    ' || `views` || ' views' FROM ptb_forum WHERE id=$forum";
```